# why is this __autoload giving me e_notice warning when using a defined constant?

Tags: php, windows, error-handling

I'm getting for some reason this notice in the code bellow, my application is working fine and it's not affecting the rest of code in any way. But I can't wrap my head around this one notice. I don't see any errors in my code. Also, I'm using _ROOT global constant in other places and it's not giving me any notice about it being undefined. Interestingly the `if (defined('_ROOT'))` evaluates to true as it's supposed to be, since obviously it's really for sure defined.

Code:

```
<?php

session_start();

//define('_DEBUG', 'YES');
define('_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__), true);

require_once _ROOT.'/config/config.php'; //no notice

function __autoload($class_name) {
   if (defined('_DEBUG')) { echo '__autoload called<br>'; }
   if (defined('_ROOT')) { echo 'root exists'._ROOT.'<br>'; } //doesn't give me a notice
   if (file_exists(_ROOT.'/app/core/'.$class_name.'.php')) { //gives me a notice
      require_once _ROOT.'/app/core/'.$class_name.'.php'; //doesn't give me a notice
   }
}

$app = new Application();
echo $app->run();
```

Notice: `Notice: Use of undefined constant _ROOT - assumed '_ROOT' in path\to\index.php on line 13`

Comment: This code works fine using PHP 5.3.5 in my local environment. You have probably already checked it, but can you check if this line is indeed triggering notice and not some other? I often find myself checking a different file/line :) Additionally, try using variable, for example `$file = _ROOT.'/app/core/'.$class_name.'.php'` and `if ( file_exists($file) )`.

Comment: as this is not on line 18, can you post all 18 lines? Are you sure you are looking in the correct file? Also retype _ROOT at line 18 - maybe one of the Os is cirylic or something other that looks like as O but is not the same character

Comment: I've no idea why that might be.  Could you, however, put the `if (file_exists...) { require_once .. }` code into the `if (defined('_ROOT'))` conditional?  It's not an ideal solution for such a strange bug - but I see no reason at all why the notice should then be printed.

Comment: @Darhazer: i'm 100% sure it's the correct line, i'll put here the whole file when i get home

Comment: @Pete171 Holy cow, i put the `if (file_exists...)` into the `if(defined)` and it doesn't give me any notice lol...

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious: `_ROOT` is not defined at the moment `__autoload()` is called (note that this can be very early in the execution of your script).

```
if (defined('_ROOT')) { echo 'root exists'._ROOT.'<br>'; }
```

doesn't give you a notice because the code within the `if` is never executed when `_ROOT` is not defined.

Comment: If his code is in same file, could you explain why `__autoload()` is running before the `define`.  Since `__autoload()` is called, the code must be loaded.